# Exception in plugin Fabric for Android Studio

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've installed the latest [Fabric plugin](https://get.fabric.io/beta) for Android Studio and it run fine for a while. Just after updating to Android Studio 1.1.0 I got this in event log:

[image]

And the NullPointerException:

```
update failed for AnAction with ID=Actions.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsAction java.lang.NullPointerException at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.CrashlyticsPlugin.getCrashlyticsBridge(CrashlyticsPlugin.java:104)
at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.actions.CrashlyticsAction.getDelegate(CrashlyticsAction.java:24)
at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.actions.CrashlyticsAction.update(CrashlyticsAction.java:34)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.java:113)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.doUpdate(Utils.java:187)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroup(Utils.java:138)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroup(Utils.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroup(Utils.java:95)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl$2.run(ActionToolbarImpl.java:927)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.updateActions(ActionToolbarImpl.java:966)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.updateActionsImmediately(ActionToolbarImpl.java:913)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.updateAllToolbarsImmediately(ActionToolbarImpl.java:72)
at com.intellij.ide.actions.SearchEverywhereAction$11$1.run(SearchEverywhereAction.java:511)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I've tried Rebuild, reinstalling the plugin, but I still get the same exception. I suspect that the exception is due to/has something to do with the Android studio update to 1.1.0.

I've reported the issue, but that doesn't solve the problem. Has anyone came across this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm seeing this issue now, I don't think it has to do with the upgrade to 1.1.0 as I did that a while ago.

Comment: Are the code bases different for Crashlytics plugin directly and Crashlytics installed via Fabric?
On Fabric, I still have this issue even after re-downloading

Comment: re-downloading fabric plugin fixed this. I wish they'd put version numbers on downloads or in the plugin download area.

Comment: Yes, it seems that redownloading the plugin and reinstalling is the way to go.

Comment: Fabric doesn't seem to care much about users. It's all about sucking our data. Too bad as the product could have been great

Answer (score 9):

## Uninstall and Re-download the plugin

I uninstalled the **Fabric** plugin and installed a newly downloaded 2.2.0 version of the plugin (don't remember) and now it seems the exception is gone.

**Note**: After the correction from @Dheeraj Bhaskar, I actually did the process for the Fabric plugin - I couldn't find an option to download a **Crashlytics** plugin.

Comment: Are the code bases different for Crashlytics plugin directly and Crashlytics installed via Fabric?
On Fabric, I still have this issue.

Comment: re-downloading fabric plugin fixed this. I wish they'd put version numbers on downloads or in the plugin download area.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a while (close Android Studio and open it again) exception reappears.

Comment: @ViksaaSkool, It hasn't reappeared on my machine yet (I restarted AS many times since).  (I installed the a newly downloaded Fabric plugin)

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to me for months. Latest version of AS. Latest download of Fabric plugin.

I have emailed support many times, but I get back the same stupid answer over and over: "You must have unzipped the plugin before importing it".

Really no I didn't. I imported the zip file like you said. But problem still occurs.

Please fix this.

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29941872/150050

Comment: Same here. login is successful, shows the "kits" selection screen and goes back to login

Comment: Guys at fabric are not very user friendly. They keep you hanging with answers for months not understanding developers cannot wait. Let's hope a replacement comes out soon.

Comment: @checklist PLEASE SEE MY SOLUTION HERE http://stackoverflow.com/a/29941872/150050

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, I'm using the latest AndroidStudio all the time and for some reason the fabric plugin was not working. The way I solved the issue is by not using Fabric Android Studio plugin and instead downloading the Fabric IntelliJ Plugin.

To make sure it works you should uninstall any fabric plugin you currently have and restart the Android Studio. Then Launch the Android Studio and install the downloaded `FabricIntelliJPlugin.zip` file as plugin and apply the changes. (don't forget to restart again)

Hope this will help.