# Crashlytics plugin (2.2.2) can't be initialized on Android Studio (1.1.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

I've restarted Android Studio (version `1.1.0` built on 18 Feb) & now Crashlytics can't be initialized with this error:

> NullPointerException: update failed for AnAction with ID=Actions.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsAction

What should I do to fix it?

I have the following in my `build.gradle` (I'm writing here only crashlytics related configurations):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your plugin version is probably outdated.

Remove the old version of plugin (File - Settings - Plugins - choose "Fabric for Android Studio" - press "Uninstall plugin").

Download the new version from Fabric dashboard (there is a button on the left bar "Download plugin". Install plugin from disk (File - Settings - Plugins - button "Install plugin from disk" on the bottom).

Comment: STILL doesnt work me, I have done this step OVER AND OVER for months and still get the same result. Crazy!

Answer (score 2):

If you can't solve this issue, I found a way that worked (Android Studio 1.1 on OSX).

Uninstall AS.

Delete the following (~ is home directory of user who runs AS):
~/.android*
~/.Android*
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android*
~/Library/Caches/Android*
~/Library/Android*
~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics*
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio*
~/Library//Saved Application State/com.google.android.studio.savedState

Then re-install Android Studio and the Fabric plugin, and it should work now.

I don't know if all the above deletes are necessary, but I could not narrow it down any further, and deleting all the above after uninstalling, then re-installing, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i am phasing similar kind of stuff in Crashlytics plug-in.

Crashlytics which is installed by colleague in their computer then  application code is continue with my computer but in my computer not updated with ***crashlytics(2.3.1) plug-in*** that's why generating ***NoClassDefFoundError***

After doing some step to achieve success..

Step:1

**Uninstall fabric plug-in and reinstall them**

(File - Settings - Plugins - choose "Fabric for Android Studio" - press "Uninstall plugin").

Step:2

**Reinstall fabric plug-in [Fabric plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/8002/22275/FabricAndroidStudioPlugin.zip)**
(File - Settings - Plugins - press "(File - Settings - Plugins - choose "Fabric for Android Studio" - press "Uninstall plugin"). "). 
**MUST REMEMBER**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="75a7814087xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

check to update value after installed new plug-in