# Fabric For Android Studio threw an unchaught NullPointerExcpetion

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using *Fabric* with both **Android Studio** and **Eclipse**, and the plugin was really an easy tool, From a couple of weeks the Plugin for Android Studio is not working any more, I have tried to install/uninstall several times with no success, this mainly happened after the plugin is moved into Repositories.
Every time on the start up of Android Studio there is a floating message says

> "Fabric for Android Studio threw an uncaught NullPointerException.
>   Disable Plugin"

, And in Event Log a message appears every 5 seconds

> "NullPointerException: update failed for AnAction with
>   ID=Actions.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsAction"

I already read this Question with no success
[Exception in plugin Fabric for Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164074/exception-in-plugin-fabric-for-android-studio)

[image]

[image]

I have posted a question too here in there Forums 
https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-for-android-studio-threw-an-unchaught-nullpointerexcpetion/58893

I hope i can find a way to install it again without problems

Thanks.

Comment: did you use lateast android studio and fabric?

Comment: @piotrek1543 Yes i tried the latest Version for Android Studio in Stable Channel and in Preview Channel. And Fabric 2.3.1

Comment: really strange issue, check i possible is update for fabric, in note downgrade it to for example 2.1

Comment: I already was having 2.1 and the plugin wasn't working, then i upgraded it and the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted Fabric support and that was their reply

> Hmm seems like something odd's going on here! This error is usually
>   due to an out of date plugin or a caching issue with Android studio.
>   I'd like to have you try deleting the cache, removing the plugin and
>   reinstalling it.
>
> To clear the cache, delete com.crashlytics here:
>   ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics
>
> Can you then uninstall and reinstall the plugin and try it again?

After trying this, the plugin was installed successfully.